# Where can I ask about the materials that make an indoors piece of furniture/device?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My question would be "What are the glowing hands of a clock made of?" Where I ask about clocks with self luminance (even without the presence of a battery).

Is there an appropriate site on Stack Exchange for such a question?

Comment: It should be something phosphorus (it "ignites" when is in contact with oxygen, a byproduct of the oxidation), so I think chemistry can be one since "Questions relating to observed chemical phenomena" are on topic there.

Comment: @Braiam after a bit of research it turns out to be Tritium, which is an hydrogen isotope whose alpha radiation reacts with fluorescent glass to create light. Perhaps Chemistry is suitable for this...